# Spring mockMvc on post form object

Tags: spring, testing, model-view-controller, mocking, mockmvc

I have the following code in my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/my")
public class MyController  {

    @RequestMapping(value="/zone/{id}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView zone(@PathVariable Long id, @Valid MyFormBean formBean){

    System.out.println(formBean.getId());
    ModelMap mod = new ModelMap();
    mod.put("test", true);
    return new ModelAndView(myViewName, model);
    }
}
```

And the following code in my MyControllerTest class

```
public class MyControllerTest {
  @InjectMocks
  private MyController myController = new MyController();

  private MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(MyController).build();

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void myTest() {
     MyFormBean formBean = new MyFormBean();
     formBean.setId(5L);
     ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

     int id = 10;

     try {
       MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/my/zone/" + id).param("formData", formData.toString())).andReturn();
     } catch(Exception e) {
       fail(e.getMessage());
     }
}
```

The id field in MyFormBean is annotated with @NotNull

So I tried various permutations of this (requestAttr, sessionAttr, etc. instead of param, and a few others) and I cannot get it to work. At best I get exceptions on the @Valid clause. Other times the test will pass without actually entering the method.

I have tried to follow a few examples but can't find anything with my specific method signature.